# Pealing lips problem

Tags: topical-cream-gel, oil-of-skin, dry-lips, dermatillomania, breaking-habits

I have a lip problem. 
So I have a habit of picking my lips, and I finally decided to quit that habit.

So I picked my bottom lip so much that it turned pink, my whole bottom lip is literally pink now.  I have also started to pick the top of my lip as you can see in the picture.(below)

Now I am trying to "grow" back my brown skin on my lip again, btw I'm black, and every time the skin starts to cover the pink areas, I get the urgency to peel of the growing skin. Yes, I have a problem.

================================

*me:* Should I show u a picture of my lips?

*stack overflow:* No.

*me:* Come on u guys need to see how it looks like.

*stack overflow:* We can imagine.

*me:* well I don't care what you say I'm gonna show u anyway.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMWcJ.jpg) [[image: Heres my lips!!!!]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMWcJ.jpg)

*stack overflow*

As u can see the pink areas use to be brown, u might notice that some brown is starting to grow back, that's because I have worked hard on trying not to pick at it. But I still do it.
Also I have a habit of licking my lips[2]

**What I try to do to fix it.**

I put some moisturizer, Cetaphil, and that only makes the skin dry and peel by itself.

I put on some Aquaphor and that makes me want to peel my skin off even more!

[2] I was wondering if I should stop putting lotion on my lips. Because I lick my lips and I get stomachaches, all the lotion getting to my stomach.

**My question **

Should I see a skin doctor?
How do I prevent myself from picking the skin off?
Is there a moisturizer specifically for lips?
How Long would it take for my whole lives to be its original in of color brown?